# pip install fails to install dependencies

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, python-packaging

**TL;DR** Even though I've specified dependencies with `install_requires` in `setup.py`, the install through `pip` fails because some dependencies can't be found.

---

I've developed a package which I intend to distribute via `PyPi`. I've created a built distribution wheel and uploaded it to `testPyPI` to see if everything is working with the upload and if the package can be installed from a user perspective.

However, when I try to `pip` install the package inside a vanilla python 2.7 environment, the installation process fails while installing the dependencies.

My package depends on these packages (which I added to the `setup.py` file accordingly):

```
...

install_requires=['numpy','gdal','h5py','beautifulsoup4','requests','tables','progress'],

...
```

So when I run pip install, everything looks normal for a moment, until I receive this error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement progress (from #NAME#) (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for progress (from #NAME#)

When I remove the progress dependency (I could live without it), same thing happens for `pytables`:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tables (from #NAME#) (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for tables (from #NAME#)

If I run `pip install tables` and `pip install progress` manually beforehand, everything works as expected.

So how can I assure that if someone downloads my package, all missing dependencies are installed with it?

**Related bonus question**:

Can I include a wheel file in my package (maybe through `MANIFEST.in`) and install it as dependency if the module is not available? If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And I think I've found the answer to my question myself.

When installing a package from `testPyPI`, the dependencies are also installed from there. And it seems, that while there are many packages available, `pytables` and `progress` are apparently missing. This caused the installation to fail.

Naturally, manually installing with `pip install` gets the package from the "normal" `PyPi`, which of course works. This obviously added to my confusion.

Here's a look at the output from `pip install` when installing the package from the `testPyPi`:

```
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4f/96/b3329750a04fcfc316f15f658daf6d81acc3ac61e3db390abe8954574c18/nump
y-1.9.3.tar.gz (4.0MB)
```

while installing the wheel directly, it looks slightly different:

```
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/91/504e434d3b95d943caab926f33dee5691768fbb622bc290a0fa6df77e1d8/numpy-1.1
4.2-cp27-none-win32.whl (9.8MB)
```

Additionally, running

```
pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ tables
```

produces the same error as described in my question.

Comment: Took a while to find this answer - thanks for documenting. My workaround was to eliminate those required installs from my package when using the testPyPi.

Comment: Oh thank you so much for this! I was going crazy! ^^There should be a way to tell pip to get dependencies from the real pypi, and not the test one